# Ionic 3 Unable to get property 'valid' of undefined or null reference

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

im trying to set up a form on a crud that i am using with firebase, and initially i was storing just a name and number both passed as strings, i added more parameters which are also string types, however i started to get the
Unable to get property 'valid' of undefined or null reference, i tried some fixes, but i couldnt get lucky... Here's my .html file

contact-edit.html

```
 <ion-header>
  <ion-navbar color="primary">
    <ion-title>{{ title }}</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  <form [formGroup]="form">
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label stacked>Unidade</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="text" formControlName="unidade"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item *ngIf="!form.controls.unidade.valid && (form.controls.unidade.dirty || form.controls.unidade.touched)" color="danger">
      <div [hidden]="!form.controls.name.errors.required">
        O campo é obrigatório
      </div>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item>
      <ion-label stacked>Endereço</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="text" formControlName="endereco"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item *ngIf="!form.controls.endereco.valid && (form.controls.endereco.dirty || form.controls.endereco.touched)" color="danger">
      <div [hidden]="!form.controls.endereco.errors.required">
        O campo é obrigatório
      </div>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item>
      <ion-label stacked>Horario</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="text" formControlName="hour"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item *ngIf="!form.controls.hour.valid && (form.controls.hour.dirty || form.controls.hour.touched)" color="danger">
      <div [hidden]="!form.controls.hour.errors.required">
        O campo é obrigatório
      </div>
    </ion-item>


    <ion-item>
      <ion-label stacked>Telefone</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="text" formControlName="tel"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item *ngIf="!form.controls.tel.valid && (form.controls.tel.dirty || form.controls.tel.touched)" color="danger">
      <div [hidden]="!form.controls.tel.errors.required">
        O campo é obrigatório
      </div>
    </ion-item>


    <ion-item>
      <ion-label stacked>Data</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="text" formControlName="date"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item *ngIf="!form.controls.date.valid && (form.controls.date.dirty || form.controls.date.touched)" color="danger">
      <div [hidden]="!form.controls.date.errors.required">
        O campo é obrigatório
      </div>
    </ion-item>


    <div padding>
      <button ion-button block type="submit" [disabled]="!form.valid" (click)="onSubmit()">Salvar</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</ion-content>
```

And if it helps here's the contact-edit.ts

```
    import { ContactProvider } from './../../providers/contact/contact';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams, ToastController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-contact-edit',
  templateUrl: 'contact-edit.html',
})
export class ContactEditPage {
  title: string;
  form: FormGroup;
  contact: any;

  constructor(
    public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams,
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private provider: ContactProvider,
    private toast: ToastController) {

    // maneira 1
    //this.contact = this.navParams.data.contact || { };
    //this.createForm();

    // // maneira 2
      this.contact = { };
    this.createForm();

    if (this.navParams.data.key) {
    const subscribe = this.provider.get(this.navParams.data.key).subscribe((c: any) => {
    subscribe.unsubscribe();

    this.contact = c;
    this.createForm();
    })
    }

    this.setupPageTitle();
  }

  private setupPageTitle() {
    this.title = this.navParams.data.contact ? 'Alterando Consulta' : 'Nova consulta';
  }

  createForm() {
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      key: [this.contact.key],
      unidade: [this.contact.unidade, Validators.required],
      endereco: [this.contact.endereco, Validators.required],
      horario: [this.contact.endereco, Validators.required],
      tel: [this.contact.tel, Validators.required],
      date: [this.contact.date, Validators.required]
    });
  }

  onSubmit() {
    if (this.form.valid) {
      this.provider.save(this.form.value)
        .then(() => {
          this.toast.create({ message: 'Contato salvo com sucesso.', duration: 3000 }).present();
          this.navCtrl.pop();
        })
        .catch((e) => {
          this.toast.create({ message: 'Erro ao salvar o contato.', duration: 3000 }).present();
          console.error(e);
        })
    }
  }
}
```

Specifically these are the errors im getting

```
> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'valid' of undefined
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (ContactEditPage.html:33)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:14697)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13844)
    at callViewAction (core.js:14195)
    at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:14127)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13850)
    at callViewAction (core.js:14195)
    at execEmbeddedViewsAction (core.js:14153)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13845)
    at callViewAction (core.js:14195)
```

Comment: you have a typo.. you are accessing `hour` in html while the ts file has `horario`. The `hour` formcontrol doesnt exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are missing a `hour` control in your form group here.

Comment: Exactly what you and Suraj Rao said, it works now :D